# barcode: generate code with set width

Tags: javascript, php, css, barcode

I have code like this

```
<div class='testbarcode' style="width:22%"></div>
     <script>
      $('.testbarcode').barcode('1234567', "code128");
</script>
```

When I set style it's break line, so how i can set width this barcode smaller than it ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you want to get your barcode smaller? What's your actual css? Why is your barcode 22% width? We need more information to help you.

Comment: You asked a similar question earlier. The fact is, that the specification on [the site](http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-jquery-plugin-201.html) tells you, you can add a "settings" object to the jQuery call.
You can even specify the width of the bars and the height.
Try `$('.testbarcode').barcode('1234567', "code128", {barWidth:1, barHeight:30});` as your jQuery call.

Answer (score 1):

By this case, I answer my own for share to someone if meet problem as me

```
1 -> barWidth: 1,
2 -> barHeight: 50,
3 -> moduleSize: 5,
4 -> showHRI: true,
5 -> addQuietZone: true,
6 -> marginHRI: 5,
7 -> bgColor: "#FFFFFF",
8 -> color: "#000000",
9 ->fontSize: 10
```

Reference [there](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Based-Barcode-Generator-Barcode.html)

Comment: is barWidth and barHeight are in px?